# Direct Message and @mention Slack users from Salesforce integration

Tags: visual-workflow, slack

I have a Salesforce/Slack integration based on the new native capabilities released in Summer '22.
I can't find how to @mention someone on the slack message I send from SF flow and how to write the message to the user's private channel.
Is the user's Slack Id saved somewhere in SF with this new native integration?
What is the right way to @mention someone in a message I write from a flow to a Slack channel?

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links below, they both reference how to @Mention a slack user in a post:

https://automationchampion.com/2022/05/24/post-a-message-to-a-slack-channel-using-flow/

https://automationchampion.com/2022/05/25/send-a-direct-slack-message-using-flow/

Hope this points you in the right direction.